# Spring boot test не видит application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

В классе, для которого пишу тест, есть переменная:

```
@Value("${key}")
private String key;
```

которая получает значение из файла `application.properties`

Само приложение видит данное значение из `application.properties`, но тесты не видят.

Тест не видит значение key, или сам файл `application.properties`.

Вот код теста:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CipherServiceTest {

    private String decryptData;
    private String encryptData;

    private CipherService cipherService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        cipherService = new CipherServiceImpl();
        decryptData = "1234567";
        encryptData = "Ql1eURhFU";
    }

    @Test
    public void encryptDataTest(){
        assertThat(cipherService.encrypt(decryptData)).isNotEqualTo(decryptData);
    }

    @Test
    public void decryptData(){
        assertThat(cipherService.decrypt(encryptData)).isEqualTo(decryptData);
    }
}
```

подскажите пожалуйста, где и как правильно прописать properties для теcтов? Читал и руководствовался, но не помогло:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html

Comment: Мой вопрос отличается тем, что само приложение видит properties. Но не видят именно тесты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте наличие файла `application.properties` в `src/test/resources/`

Comment: Отсутствовал, добавил, не помогло.

Comment: Для  `private CipherService cipherService` проставь аннотацию `@Autowired`, чтобы spring сконфигурировал тебе данный сервис со всеми его настройками, включая нужное поле из `application.properties`. И убери `cipherService = new CipherServiceImpl();`, этим ты перезатираешь сконфигурированный в spring класс...

Comment: да, ты прав. Теперь работает :) спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить аннотацию `@SpringBootTest` к классу

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CipherServiceTest {}
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html), пункт `45.4.1`

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Для тестов спринг использует [`@TestPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) вместо [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html). Эта аннотация имеет более высокий приоритет:

```java
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
```

Можно указать аннотацию [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html):

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"key1=value1", "key2=value2"})
```

Comment: Тоже пробовал. Увы не помогло. Может в pom.xml нужно что-то прописать?